# Selection in a UITableViewController Disapears inside a UINavigationController when navigating back to the TableView Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

As The description says
I have a table view controller inside navigation controller I select a row in the table view and when I navigate to the next page and navigate back my selection has now disapered.

I have set the clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear to no. and it shouldent matter because when poping back in the navigation Controller ViewWillAppear is not called is there something I am missing.

Regards Christian

Comment: Please check if anywhere inside your code contains [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; If there is, remove that.

Comment: I havent written all the code my self but I am pretty sure there is no deselect selectors being called

Comment: Can you add some codes or update a sample project on github. Someone should be able to help you troubleshoot after this.